# System.getUriFor где хранятся значения?

Tags: java, android

Собственно вопрос в заголовке
Хочу заменить значение "launchMiBrowserWhileSwipe"

```
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(System.getUriFor("launchMiBrowserWhileSwipe"), true, this.mGlobalEdgeObserver);
```

Comment: очень мало информации, добавьте конкретики больше.

Comment: Какой конкретики? (System.getUriFor("launchMiBrowserWhileSwipe") задан где-то в системе, но где?

Comment: где и как вы пытаетесь это сделать? насколько я понял вы хотите изменить системные настройки для браузера?

Comment: Команда "launchMiBrowserWhileSwipe" запускает по свайпу поиск в браузере, хочу заменить чтобы запускать другое приложение